# how to find web pages by part of url by google

Tags: google-search

I want to scan some WordPress websites and need to find some target websites.
For that, I need to find URLs that contains some exact text and i just know this could be done by google (cuz i used it before but i cant remember how).
For this case, I want to find wp sites, That would be done by searching for urls that containes "wp-admin.php". something like this :
urls contains ("wp-admin.php")
I've googled for it but nothing found.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really sounds like "please help me to hack websites" you know, right? Anyway, this is off-topic, really. How would you search for anything on the web programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution to find web pages by part of he URL in Google:

```
allinurl:wp-login.php
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.